# Why is this async function not awaiting

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following function

```
const refresh = async req => {
    const authorization = req.headers['authorization'];

    if (!authorization) throw new Error("You need to login");
    accesstoken = authorization.split(' ')[1];
    //..... a lot of code
}
module.exports =  {
    refresh
}
```

And then I call this in another file

```
    function requireLogin(req,res,next){
    try {

        const userId = isAuth(req)
        if (userId !== null) {
            next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if(err.message == "jwt expired"){
            console.log("jwt was expired")
            async function result(){
                console.log("inside result function")
                var data = await refresh(req)
                console.log(data) //undefined
            }
            result();
        }
        res.send({
            error: `${err.message}`
        })
    }
}
```

So its basically not awaiting my function.
If I console.log() the desired result inside my function, I can see it happening properly, but well i cant log it in the main file, since its not awaiting.

The syntax seems fine to me i dont know.

EDIT: This is the whole code of refresh

```
const refresh = async req => {
const authorization = req.headers['authorization'];

if (!authorization) throw new Error("You need to login");
accesstoken = authorization.split(' ')[1];
var userId = verify(accesstoken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { ignoreExpiration: true })
userId = userId.userId

var token = ""

db.query("SELECT * FROM user_permisson WHERE user_id='" + userId + "'").then(function (data) {
    var permited = [];
    console.log("permisos de usuario")
    delete data[0].user_id
    for (var key in data[0]) {
        if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (data[0][key] === true) {
                permited.push(key)
            }
            console.log(key + " -> " + data[0][key]);
        }
    }
    console.log(permited)

    //CASE 1(Front end): this is for the case when its coming from rect and is unable to read the private cookie, so it received an encrypted id that will identify the user so we are able to get its refresh token, client to server connection
    //now the we need to grab the refreshtoken of the user knowing its id
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" + userId + "'").then(function (data) {
        var user = data;
        token = user[0].refreshtoken;
        var id = user[0].id;
        if (!token) return { accesstoken: '' };
        let payload = null;

        try {
            payload = verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
        } catch (err) {
            return { accesstoken: '' };
        }

        user = "";
        db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" + id + "'").then(function (data) {
            user = data;
            if (!user) return { accesstoken: '' };
            //if user exists check if refreshtoken exist on user

            if (user[0].refreshtoken !== token) {
                return { accesstoken: '' }
            }

            //if token exist create a new Refresh and Accestoken
            const accesstoken = createAccessToken(user[0].id, permited);
            const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken(user[0].id);


            db.query("UPDATE users SET refreshtoken = '" + refreshtoken + "' WHERE id = '" + user[0].id + "';").then(function (data) {
                // sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken); //unnecesary
                console.log(accesstoken)
                return { accesstoken }; //THIS IS THE RETURN I WANT TO HAPPEN <---------------------------------------

            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", error)
            })


        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", error)
            return error;
        })
    })
```

})
}

Comment: Where is the return statement within the function `refresh`?

Comment: Are you sure of using async on the function `refresh`?

Comment: Looks like `result();` should be `await result();` as well?

Comment: @Ele i will past the whole code 1 sec

Comment: And that requires it to be `async function requireLogin`

Comment: If you don't return a value in `refresh`. It will get `undefined` when run an async function.

Comment: @Ele updated with the code, the return is by the end of it, i market id with an arrow coment

Comment: pls count your await statements ? on a quick look its <= 0

Comment: @Estradiaz i have an await in the result() function inside my main app which is calling an async function wich is refresh

Comment: The only `return` inside `refresh` are ***inside callbacks*** to other async functions. `refresh` itself has no `return`. You need to treat those nested async callbacks the same way with `await` if you want to `return` from `refesh` directly.

Comment: I think you should return a Promise.

Comment: @Ele `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar over promises, you can do either, depending on what you prefer. Arguably `await` is more readable, which is its entire reason for existing in the first place. OP would need to rewrite `refresh` to properly use `await` *instead* of using `then`…

Comment: @deceze I didn't realize the Promise use on db.query functions.

Comment: solved, i was missing return in each db.query

Comment: "//..... a lot of code" - any of it asynchronous?